# Unexpected array behavior when passed through EJS in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have an array of Strings in my `users.js` which I render to my ejs page and then there is an `onclick` method where it is passed to a js function like below
`users.js`

```
console.log("count ",count);
res.render("index2", {title: 'some data', imgsrc : variabled, coun : count});
```

and `index2.ejs`

```
<button onclick="popu('<%= coun %>');">
```

and `popu()` is

```
function popu(coun) {
    var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");

    for(var i = 0; i < coun.length; i++) {
        var opt = coun[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

So, basically it is filling a drop-down menu. The problem is that `console.log(count)` consoles this

```
count  [
  'Forest', 'Ocean',
  'Port', 'Airport',
]
```

but the drop-down menu is

```
F
o
r
e
....
```

And I am unable to get why is the array iterating over these strings too.

Note: the `count` array was formed by pushing `mongodb` query results like this

```
var count = [];

var arr = await coll.find().toArray();
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        val = String(arr[i].Name)
        count.push(val);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If `coun` is an array, what exactly do you think `'<%= coun %>'` is going to produce?

Comment: @Phil Nothing, I assume it is passing that array to the function

Comment: @Phil So basically it was passing a string to the function. That's why whole object was iterated as a string.

Comment: Yep. I wouldn't recommend injecting objects into HTML attributes, it's bound to have a problem with quote nesting